# Create an global array containing floating numbers

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, arrays, nsmutablearray

I wanted to create 2 global arrays which can be updated during the run of the programme.In each update i add one element to zeroth position and deleted the last number
I created the arrays as....
In the .h file..........
//////////////

```
@interface Shared : NSObject{
NSMutableArray *x;
NSMutableArray *y;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *x;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *y;
+(Shared*)sharedInstance;

@end
```

In .m file

```
staticShared* sharedInstance;
@implementation Shared
@synthesize  x; 
@synthesize  y;

+(Shared*)sharedInstance
{
if (!sharedInstance) {
sharedInstance=[[Sharedalloc]init];
    }
returnsharedInstance;
}

-(Shared*)init
{
self = [superinit];
if(self)
    {
x=[[NSMutableArrayalloc] init];
x=[NSMutableArrayarrayWithObjects:@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",nil];
y=[[NSMutableArrayalloc] init];
y=[NSMutableArrayarrayWithObjects:@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",nil];
    }
returnself;
}
@end
```

Then i used to call them and re,ove and added elements using the following code....

```
[[shared sharedInstance].y removeLastObject];
[[shared sharedInstance].y insertObject:new_element atIndex:0];

[[shared sharedInstance].x removeLastObject];
[[shared sharedInstance].x insertObject:new_element atIndex:0];
```

In the mean time i call these values and calculate an arithmetic value using an expression.

This seems to work well. But it seems to be an inefficient way to handle floating point numbers which i store in it. As these arrays creates objects. Is there any easy method that i can create a global array containing specified amount of floating point numbers and update it during the run of the programm(array size is fixed) by deleting the last object, and call them back to do calculation?

Please help me!

EDIT 1
 To sir deanWombourne
.................................
I implement as you instructed! Can you please go through this and help me to correct 2 errors i get.

IN the .h file

```
@interface Shared : NSObject{
@private
float input[7];
float output[6];

}
+(Shared*)sharedInstance;

-(void)addNewInput:(float)input1;
-(float *)input;
-(void)addNewOutput:(float)output1;
-(float *)output;

@end
```

in .m file............

```
@implementation Shared

-(id)init{
if((self =[superinit])){

for(int n=0; n<7 ;++n)
input[n]=0.00f;

for(int n=0; n<6 ;++n)
output[n]=0.00f;
    }
returnself;
}

-(void)addNewInput:(float)input1{
input[0]=input[1];
input[1]=input[2];
input[2]=input[3];
input[3]=input[4];
input[4]=input[5];
input[5]=input[6];
input[6]=input1;
}

-(float *)input {
returninput;
}


-(void)addNewOutput:(float)output1{
output[0]=output[1];
output[1]=output[2];
output[2]=output[3];
output[3]=output[4];
output[4]=output[5];
input[5]=output1;
}

-(float *)output {
returnoutput;
}
@end
```

When calling it

```
float reading=  (accel_reading)/(1.165969038*1e5f);
[[SharedsharedInstance] addNewInput:reading];
```

Problems i get
1. In the implementation, it says incomplete implementation (it's a warning not an error)
2. How can i used a for loop to fill array values or is this way ok?

Major problem i get, 
When i call it as shown above, program stops running telling 
Terminating application due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason '+[SharedsharedInstance]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x5780'

Please help me through this...............

Comment: Incapsulate methods that add new elements to array, so you will handle a float to them and they will do all other stuff. Also you can create a dynamic list using struct. [Here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t670357-dynamic-list-of-structures.html) you can find some discussion about such lists. Using structures your code will work much more faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code [Smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) (and I mean that in the nicest possible way!)

Using two parallel arrays and keeping in sync is a bad design pattern (and a performance hit in quite a few ways!). Especially as there is already a struct that handles storing an `x` and `y` at the same time - [CGPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGPoint)).

You're solving the '*only objects go in arrays*' problem by converting your `float' primitives to`NSString` objects, which is horrendously inefficient - take a look instead at the [NSValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, it's designed to put native C primitives into an object without expensive parsing operations :)

You might also want to look into [malloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/malloc.3.html) (and `free` etc) and deal with the whole problem at the C level - this will mean no objects at all and would be blindingly fast (at the cost of more complicated code).

Hope this helps, if you have any questions just add a comment to this answer :)

---

EDIT

If all you want to do is store 4 x and y values, then this is probably the easiest way to do it :

```
@interface Shared : NSObject {
@private
    CGPoint points[4];
}

+(Shared *)sharedInstance;

- (void)addNewPoint:(CGPoint)point;
- (CGPoint *)points;

@end

@implementation

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        // Start with 0,0 for all your points
        for (int n = 0; n < 4; ++n)
            points[n] = CGPointZero;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addNewPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    // Just move all the points along one and add the new one to the end
    // (yes, this could be done in a loop but there's not that much point for 4 points!)
    points[0] = points[1];
    points[1] = points[2];
    points[2] = points[3];
    points[3] = point;
}

- (CGPoint *)points {
    return points;
}

@end
```

This gives you a method `addNewPoint` that removes the first point and adds the new point to the end of your array.

You also get the method `points` that returns the 4 points. Use it something like :

```
// To add a point
CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(100, 100);
[[Shared sharedInstance] addNewPoint:newPoint];

// To do something with the points (in this case, NSLog them)
CGPoint *points = [[Shared sharedInstance] points];
for (int n = 0; n < 4; ++n)
    NSLog(@" Point %i : %@", n, NSStringFromCGPoint(points[n]));
```

---

EDIT #2

From your comments, you need two arrays, one with input data and one with output data. Try something like this :

```
@interface Shared : NSObject {
    float inputs[4];
    float outputs[5];
}
...
```

This will give you two arrays to read/write to - one called inputs and the other called outputs. Access them in pretty much the same way you did the ones in my first edit :

```
float *inputs = [[Shared sharedInstance] inputs];
for (int n = 0; n < 4; ++n)
    NSLog(@" Input %i : %f", n, inputs[n]);

float *outputs = [[Shared sharedInstance] outputs];
for (int n = 0; n < 5; ++n)
    NSLog(@" Output %i : %f", n, output[n]);
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Thank you very much. Actually the reason behind creating these arrays is i wanted to add the accelerometer data from the ipod(only reading x) to these arrays inside a function that activates the accelerometer. Then i have array_x (with size 4) which inputs a new reading and delete the oldest reading. Then i use theses values to calculate an arithmetic output(with an predefined equation) and add the new output to the array_y and deletes the oldest output. As accelerometer updates data at a higher rate. I need to do it quickly. Sir i m new to programming. can you please help me!

Comment: Dear sir, Thank you very much for your answer! But I m bit lost with it, Since i insert the new reading to the array and then used it to do my calculation, after that i need to enter the result of the calculation to my second array. So by this method how can i access it at two different times?

Comment: Dear sir sorry for the misunderstanding, Size of one array is 4 and the other one is 5. So two different array sizes! Sir your ideas and answers are source of knowledge for me! Appreciate your effort!

Comment: Ah, so you're not storing X and Y values together, you're storing input and output values separately. My code example won't work for you then :) See EDIT #2.

Comment: Dear sir you are god to me, Really! May all ur dreams come true. You pointed me a way to come out of the problem that i suffered almost for last week. Sir i implement my answer as u instructed! But got few bugs(very small ones) as i feel, i edited my original question with your method. can you please go through it and suggest me changes. Thank you!

Comment: Program stop at this point-----> [[SharedsharedInstance] addNewInput:reading]; Giving the error i mentioned above!

Comment: The error is fairly self explanatory - it says you haven't implemented the method `sharedInstance`. I bet that's what your warning is talking about as well. You have declared it in your .h file but not implemented it in your .m file. The code I provided was to get your array of floats working, the rest of the Shared class is up to you!

Comment: Dear sir i edited my original question. I did my implementation as well as i have shown in the edited question. can you please refer it.

Comment: Sorry sir! Your correct! I found my bug! Please reply to this link if i ask you a question in future~ God be with you! At last, i need to know is this method good in computing values than i used? because my program needs to run faster?

Answer (score 0):

Would a linked list be overkill for what you're trying to achieve? It's not quite as simple as a static array of floats, but makes the removal of the last object and insertion of the zeroth object reasonably simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array containing a specific number of Objects, you can use NSArray, which is static, opposed to NSMutableArray.

As for the array being Global, just implement a singleton class that contains the 2 arrays and provides the associated methods.

in Globals.h:

```
@interface Globals : NSObject

+ (Globals *) sharedGlobals;

@end
```

in Globals.m:

```
@implementation Globals

static Globals *sharedGlobals = nil;

+ (Globals *) sharedGlobals{
    @synchronized(self){
        if (sharedGlobals == nil){
            sharedGlobals = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedGlobals;
}
```

you then can access the arrays (after you implemented them) with the following line:

```
[[Globals sharedGlobals] getArrayX];
```

Comment: I m relatively new to programming, Can you please tell me how to create 2 arrays from ur single tone class having a fixed number of floating point numbers and use them(for eg:- multiply the 2nd element with 5ith element) please! N thank you for ur valuable answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch to get you going.

Your array size is fixed and only contains floating point numbers, start with a C array:

```
double x[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
double y[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

The number of elements in these arrays can be calculated rather than hard-coded:

```
int xCount = sizeof(x)/sizeof(double);
int yCount = sizeof(y)/sizeof(double);
```

Now use these arrays as a circular buffer, declare a cursor and initialise:

```
int xCursor = 0;
```

The item at the front of the queue is at the cursor:

```
valueAtFrontOfQueue = x[xCursor];      // get the current front item
```

To remove the value at front and add a new one to the rear replace the value at the cursor with the new value and increment the cursor:

```
x[xCursor] = newValueForBackOfQueue;   // replace it with new item for back of queue
xCursor = (xCursor + 1) % xCount;      // and advance cursor using mod arithmetic to it cycles around
```

No wrapping doubles as objects, no dynamic allocation at all.

Wrap the above up as you see fit, maybe as a class, and you're done.

Comment: How can i define these arrays(containing floating point numbers) globally in xcode environment. and access dynamically as i wanted to update the array when a new reading from accelerometer comes and delete the oldest one. Then compute a certain asthmatic value and insert to the other array. at the same time i want to delete the oldest arithmetic value calculated!